# Sharing code between Java backend and Android app

Tags: java, android, maven

I'm developing a backend application in Java 8 and I'd like to share some code with an Android app someone else is developing (mainly DTOs), and so I have a few questions I'd like to ask:

1. Is it enough to set the `maven.compiler.target` property to `1.6` for the module containing the DTOs/common methods?
2. What if I "mistakenly" use some of the new Java 8 features/APIs like `java.time` in that same module?
3. What are some of the best practices for sharing JARs between these two very different kind of application?

Comment: Do the downvoters even care to explain?